# What does the expression "Goodbye eighth place, hi checkered flag" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

I have heard the following expression in a racing game's description:

> Goodbye eighth place, hi checkered flag.

As far as I remember, the context was about getting bonus points by collecting the identical items while racing. This triggers a mode in which the player becomes invincible.

Maybe I am missing something that can be guessed by native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

We use goodbye colloquially to refer to a position we are no longer in anymore, and doesn't have to be in conversation. For example:

> Goodbye high school, hello college!

In your example, it probably means that the mode in which the player is invincible allows the player to leave eighth place, which would be considered quite bad, and go to the *checkered flag*.

In a race, a checkered flag represents the finish line. So, to recap, the sentence means that once achieving this invincibility, the player will not be in the low position that they are in and will be able to get to the finish line.

Comment: Goodbye X, Hello Y. is an idiom in English.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual in motor-racing that when the winning car crosses the finish line a checkered flag is waved.

So in this context it means that the racer has gone from eighth place to first place.

This ties in with your recollection of the context.